# Sendmail service is not starting and giving the error message on CentOS7

Tags: centos, sendmail, centos7

I am trying to start sendmail service on centos7,but it gives me the below error message Which is very Vague. Could someone help me to identify the issue?

```
Apr 12 01:04:25 server.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Sendmail Mail Transport Agent...
Apr 12 01:04:25 server.localdomain systemd[1]: PID file /run/sendmail.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Apr 12 01:04:25 server.localdomain sendmail[3712]: starting daemon (8.14.7): SMTP+queueing@01:00:00
Apr 12 01:05:55 server.localdomain systemd[1]: sendmail.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Apr 12 01:05:55 server.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Sendmail Mail Transport Agent.
Apr 12 01:05:55 server.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit sendmail.service entered failed state.
Apr 12 01:05:55 server.localdomain systemd[1]: sendmail.service failed.
```

I am using centos7.

```
    #rpm -qa | grep -i sendmail
  sendmail-8.14.7-5.el7.x86_64
  sendmail-cf-8.14.7-5.el7.noarch
```

Is there any know issues with sendmail with centos7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible reason:

You have in the sendmail.mc 2x the line
`DAEMON_OPTIONS('Port=smtp, Name=MTA')dnl`

### My solution

I had the same problem, 
in the sendmail.mc I had the lines like this

```
# DAEMON_OPTIONS('Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS('Port=smtp, Name=MTA')dnl
```

I thought I had commented it out, but to comment a line out in this file it has to be:
`dnl # DAEMON_OPTIONS('Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl`

How I tried to solve this was:

I used a different port than 'smpt' (which is default port 25) and changed it into port 26 (replace 'smtp' with '26')

`nano /etc/mail/sendmail.mc`
`DAEMON_OPTIONS('Port=26,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl`

Rebuild sendmail and restart the service:
`make -C /etc/mail`
`sudo systemctl restart sendmail`

Then the service started correctly without any errors and email send before arrived in the mail boxes.

Then I changed the port back from `26` to `smtp`

Then
`make -C /etc/mail`
`sudo systemctl restart sendmail` 
`sudo systemctl status sendmail`

And the service was working fine again without errors

Check on which port sendmail is working:
`netstat -anp | grep LISTEN | grep sendmail`

This fixed this issue on my Centos 7 server.
`sendmail-8.14.7-5.el7.x86_64`